# No se encuentra un archivo que tengo instalado

Tags: javascript, validación, importación, frontend, javascript-import

Estoy realizando un proyecto super básico de validación de formulario para aprender a manejar Vest. Sin embargo, al momento de importar las classnames del framework, en la consola de mi navegador (la aplicación esta corriendo en localhost), aparece este error.

`net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`.

La manera en la que importo los archivos en cuestión es la siguiente:

`import classnames from /vest/classnames`

Si decido deshacerme del primer /, entonces un nuevo error aparece:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vest/classnames". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Sin embargo sin dicho primer slash, en mi editor de código, aparece el tamaño del modulo lo que quiere decir que la ruta es correcta, pero al poner el slash salta el primer error.

Comment: y si pones `/vest/classnames` entre comillas `"/vest/classnames"`?

Comment: ¿y si haces caso a lo que dice el error y pones **`import classnames from ./vest/classnames`** ? (con un punto al ser una ruta relativa que empieza allí donde se ejecuta ese código)